# Gitlab CI failing cannot find aws command

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set up a pipeline that builds my react application and deploys it to my AWS S3 bucket. It is building fine, but fails on the deploy.

My .gitlab-ci.yml is :

```
image: node:latest

variables:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: $S3_BUCKET_NAME

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - aws s3 cp --recursive ./build s3://MYBUCKETNAME
```

It is failing with the error:

```
sh: 1: aws: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you AWS CLI is not installed in the CI environment. You probably need to use GitLab’s AWS Docker image. Please read the [Cloud deployment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#aws) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

@jellycsc is spot on. 
Otherwise, if you want to just use the node image, then you can try something like Thomas Lackemann details ([here](https://lacke.mn/blog/continuous-integration-using-gitlab-with-elastic-beanstalk)), which is to use a shell script to install; python, aws cli, zip and use those tools to do the deployment. You'll need AWS credentials stored as environment variables in your gitlab project.
I've successfully used both approaches.

Comment: Looks like the Thomas Lackemann link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Install "awscli" at the beginning of script.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip
    - pip install awscli
    - aws s3 cp --recursive ./build s3://MYBUCKETNAME
```